# Create repository link inside other repository

Tags: git, directory-structure

I recently started migrating my projects from svn into git. One of the problems we had with our previous folder structure was that at times in older projects it was difficult to track all of its dependencies (e.g. Base Apis/ frameworks that we have in the company) So I thought one simple form to avoid this was to create links inside a project repo. Example:

Main Project

- -------------> DB
- -------------> WebApplication
- -------------> BaseAPI (this would be a link)
- -------------> BaseFramework (this would be a link)

That way I could guarantee that everything that is shared with other projects but still a dependency in this project will be tied together. The link does not need to do anything rather than "show" the project there.

Does anyone have any ideas on what can be done? Or if obviously there are better ways to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these dependencies are under git version control, you could use [**git submodule**](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

That way, you can put git repositories inside the main git repository, and the main repository will remember which version of the children to checkout.

That way, whenever someone pulls your repository, all dependencies call also be pulled with the right version.

Comment: Thanks Fox that seems to be even better and exactly what I was looking for! Thanks